# What kind of database to use to store a word list and then search back the words fast if I have a multiset with alowed letters?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have a huge word list, around 1 million words.  If I use relational DB like MySQL or SQL Server and put all the words in one single column of one table, what performance may I expect? What the database must do is simple: just search for a word that contains some of the given letters (example: A O E P L M N U S). (Like a game of Scrabble) That must produce the result:

```
 maple
 ample
 mole
 lamp
 palm
 mope
 poem
```

and etc...

What do you thinking? Can I expect fast enough response from the DB?
What data base I have to use, is MySQL good choice? I have no others except SQL SERVER 2010.

Comment: This has as much to do with jquery as with french fries :)

Comment: i think more than DB you need a very powerful server, also you must optimize your code to run fast as possible.

Comment: I'm thinking of using my local resources at first time - Intel Core i3 + 4GB ddr3.. and about the code, may be C# or php, it depends.. but I need just to execute a proper SQL query, I think.. nothing especially more.

Comment: i'm not sure something like MYSQL LIKE can be fast enough to do this for you or not, maybe you need to help MySQL with divide words or separate tables or make an indexing system.

Comment: There's no such thing as SQL Server 2010, by the way. Your version is likely SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I'm agree with you. I was saying that I have a legal license just for 2010's version, this is what I have and I'm awoled to use free. And yes - semantically there are no difference between 2008 and 2010, the relations are relations, the tupples are tupples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for test purposes [I have been developed and approach for a solution of your scenario](http://beutil.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/pujar-aplicacio-mvc-3-dinahosting.html). This solutions is build with [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and SQL-Server.

I have modeling a N:M relationship between words ('paraules') and letters ('lletres'), how many times a letter appear in a word:

[image]

I have also wrote EF query with linq:

[image]

[You can test performance here (until feb 2013)](http://www.joincar.cat/a/search/go).

Comment: It seems interesting, I'm gonna think about it. At first time SQL server will be satisfiable, but then I must figure out a way to move to MySql or something else free for use. Thank you.

Comment: If I will rewrite it, I will exclude EF layer from equation. Also, you should take a look to NOSQL approach as mongodb.